# Word isnt applying formating

Tags: microsoft-word

I defined a format:

As you can see `Cursive` is enabled and `Bold` is disabled.

[image]

When I apply this format to a text line, Bold is applied but `Cursive` is not
[image]

As you can see in the first screenshot, this format is based on the format `p`. When I for into the `p` settings, there is not `Bold` defined. This `Bold` is coming from nowhere.

How can I apply a format and then be done with it, like in InDesign. Word just does something and doesn't care for settings it seem.

Comment: Hi. MS Word isn't graphic design software. Might be better to ask this on Super User.

Comment: yeah tell me about it 